# SEO problem with mispelled domain

Tags: seo, google-search, google-index

I have site named `janvhitravels.in`. On Google Search when we type *janvhi travels* it show search result for *jahnavi travels*.

Google thinks that *janvhi* is wrong spelling and *jahnavi* is wrong. So my site not appers in the list.

If I click on "Search instead for janvhi travels" then my site shows up.

Can we stop Google think like that? Is there any solution for this?

[image: screen 1 for initial search]

[image: screen 2 mentioning my site]

Answer (score 0):

Make some good backlinks with *janvhi travels* with some keyword variations, you must get your website with same keyword within 1-2 months.